# PERMISSION DENIED

Tags: sublimetext3

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file C:\Users\Kratik\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User/hii.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 0.6s]
```

[image]

Whenever I make a new program in the sublime, it shows the above error.

Comment: May be this could help https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/permission-denied-error/49584

Answer (score 1):

It seems that answer is well explained in [SublimeText forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/collect2-exe-error-ld-returned-1-exit-status/13129/6) and you should always googling trying to find already known answers.

Basically you get that error when you build a program that is already running, so it is locked by Windows.

In your case probably the error is due to gathering input: Sublime doesn’t forward any input that you type into the output panel to your running program.

As from the answer in [SublimeText forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/collect2-exe-error-ld-returned-1-exit-status/13129/6):

> The solution there is either don’t execute (console) programs from
> Sublime that need to take interactive input, or if you do use a build
> system that will first open a command prompt window and execute your
> program in that; then you can interact with it directly.

Comment: As an addendum to that answer, since then the [Terminus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus) package was released, which makes it very easy to create a build system that allows for interactive input (details in the package README).